# Firefox add-on: inject content script to iframe with src as "about:blank"

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

We are developing an add-in, and would like to have the content script being injected into the top page and all frames. However we found that the content scripts cannot be injected into iframe with src as **"about:blank"** or **"javascript:..."**.

Any comment/suggestion?

sample page-mod:

```
require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod({
            include:["*", "file://*"],
            contentScriptFile: [
                "./content/content.js",
            ],
            attachTo: ["existing","top", "frame"],...
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to update an interesting fact that detected by my teammate Wayland:

The funny thing is that it will work if we build the iframe as following:

It's like if we flush by iframe content by calling '**document.write**'.

```js
function buildme() {

  var iframe = ...;
  iframe.contentDocument.open();
  iframe.contentDocument.write("<html><body></body></html>");
  iframe.contentDocument.close()

  var child = iframe.contentDocument.craeteElement("..");
  ...
  iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(child);
}

< iframe id = "myframe"
onload = "buildme();" / >
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an option of `match_about_blank` in the content script of firefox now:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts#match_about_blank

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod({
        include:["*", "file://*", "about:blank", "javascript:*"],
        contentScriptFile: [
            "./content/content.js",
        ],
        attachTo: [[b]"existing","top", "frame"[/b]],...
```

Comment: Sorry for late replay, but unfortunately, this is not working in Firefox add-on.